# JavaScript/jQuery Assigning Value Between Variables and ElementByID

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, getelementbyid

to assign a numerical value to a variable in JavaScript we do this:

```
var x = 3;
```

Questions:

1. How do you assign a value of a form text field to a variable through getElementByID and jQuery?
2. How do you assign a value of a variable to a form text field through getElementByID and jQuery?

I am trying to do this:

I want to calculate numbers entered in a couple of form fields. Send the values to a variable then pass the total to a different form field through either getElementByID or $('#textbox'). I am a little confused on the syntax.

Beginner here...

Comment: FYI, there is no `getElementByID` ?

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById('field').value;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Let me try doing it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the variable to input using jquery:

```
$('#inputId').val(x);
```

Assign the value of input to variable using jquery:

```
var x = $('#inputId').val();
```

Assign the variable to input using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').value = x;
```

Assign the value of input to variable using javascript:

```
x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
```

[Fiddle using Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/cgc80fua/)

[Fiddle using Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/cgc80fua/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Let me try that again from my end.

Comment: And thank you for sharing Fiddle... I just learned of it from you. I'll start working on that tool from now own.